# How do I make the last RewriteRule execute if the RewriteRules above it are not matched?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I make the last RewriteRule execute in the Rewrite list below if none of the RewriteRules are matched? (a bit like a catch all rule)?

What I have is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} referrer=as
RewriteRule ^legal/privacy$ /about/privacy [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^Disclaimer$ /about/legal [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^Privacy-Collection-Statement$ /about/privacy [L,NC,R=301]
# Catch all rule below
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://company.com/about [NC,R=301]
```

So if the URL is:

```
http://company.com/blah/blah?referrer=as
```

it would redirect to (using the catch all rule):

```
http://company.com/about?referrer=as
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have a negative condition in the catch-all rule to make it fire for everything that has already not been redirected to:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} referrer=as
RewriteRule ^legal/privacy$ /about/privacy [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^Disclaimer$ /about/legal [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^Privacy-Collection-Statement$ /about/privacy [L,NC,R=301]

# Catch all rule below
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/about/(privacy|legal|privacy)?[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://company.com/about/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

Here `!^about/(privacy|legal|privacy)/?$` pattern is a **negative match pattern** that matches everything which is not `/about/privacy` and not `/about/legal` and not `/about/privacy`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  What you say makes sense however if I enter the following URL:

localhost/legal/privacy?referrer=as

I expect the first RewriteRule to fire however the catch all rule is firing.  I've cleared my cache / browsing history and all.  If I comment out the catchall rule, the first rule fires when using the URL above.  Any ideas of something missing perhaps?

Comment: With just these rules in my .htaccess when I open `/legal/privacy?referrer=as` it gets correctly redirected to `/about/privacy?referrer=as`. Do you have other rules also or any .htaccess in `/about/` directory as well?

Comment: Very strange.  I've commented out everything else in the file other than what you probably have.  If I comment out the negative match pattern rule it redirects to the /about/privacy?referrer=as  If I uncomment out the negative match pattern rule it's executed.  When you say try updated rule once, what do you mean?  It's almost as if I should be saying when the first rule is matched (L flag) stop.

Comment: I mean I have made an update in the rule. Did you try updated last rule?

Answer (score 0):

Should be the L|last flag

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html

"The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed."

```
Rule A [L]
Rule B [L]
Rule C [L]
Catchall rule
```